# Complex javascript object access in PHP POST var

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a complex Javascript object which is sent to PHP server with $.ajax:

the object looks like:

```
var obj = 
{
  sellerId:"1234",
  buyerId:"5432",
  .
  .
  .
  items:[{id:"11",qt:"3"},{id:"22",qt:"5"},{id:"33",qt:"8"}...]
};
```

jquery code looks something like this:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php.php",
      data: obj
      }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( msg );
      });
```

on PHP side the following code will echo the sellerId

```
<?php   
      echo $_POST['id'];  
?>
```

My question is how do I access the items array and its
object properties? Thanks

Comment: You can access the items using loops, have you tried this ?

Comment: Sorry not echo $_POST['id'] but echo $_POST['sellerId'] will echo the seller id on server side PHP!!!

Comment: Simple stuff to start..just use var_dump($_POST) to check what you are getting and try to use it on your own..once u face problem with handing, ask the dirty part then

Comment: Thanks swapnesh! Actually I am new in PHP. I did not know how to do that. But your snippet at the bottom did help and solved it! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Its all good even an year back I dont know about this too..but this is how we learn..good to hear u solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can retrieve the value using below code at your php file.

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $val){
    echo $val['id']."==".$val['qt'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question I slightly created some code for you to start(may be not avery good code but yes u can learn something from this) --

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var path='getdata.php'; 
var obj = {
  sellerId:"1234",
  buyerId:"5432",
  items:[{id:"11",qt:"3"},{id:"22",qt:"5"},{id:"33",qt:"8"}]
};

jQuery("#test").click(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        data: obj,
        success:function(results)
        {   
            jQuery('#venue').html(results);
        }
        });
});

});
</script>


<div id="test">This is my active div</div>

<div id="venue"></div>
```

**PHP Code in getdata.php**

```
<?php
foreach($_GET['items'] as $myitem )
{
    foreach( $myitem as $key => $value )
    {
    echo "This is my key : ".$key." This is value of key ".$value."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

**RESULT**

[image]